# Can't retrieve profile info using fb api in php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve Facebook user's information using Facebook api in PHP. But when I try to run the following code, the no content is displayed, especially because of the `require` statement. The HTML content on this page is not rendered. In other words, nothing works. Only the `echo` above require statements executes. I have correct APP ID and Secret Code.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
$somevar=$_SESSION['newsession'];
$somevar2=$_SESSION['newsession2'];
echo "rahul fb";
require 'fblib/src/Facebook/Facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '⁠
myappid',
  'secret' => 'mysecretid',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

To make API calls:

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    echo "SFDFFD";
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}else{
  echo "fatal error";
}
//echo "sdfdsfdf";
?>
```

What can be the issue? Am I doing it in right way? or is there any other way?

Comment: You should not display usernames, passwords, keys, secrets in your code example.

Comment: check your error logs

Comment: already did that.. the page is loading as a blank page.. only the first echo is working

Comment: Then configure your PHP properly to show you errors, and/or log them to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to require the autoload.php to make it work.

Also change the syntax:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '⁠
{1821595718085107}',
  'secret' => '{d17998fdecdeab3c158970c1fcbf89f4}',
));
```